# Create 3 divs into one foreach

Tags: php

Ok i am using codeIgniter to get resuts from database

```
class Video extends CI_Model{

public function getVideo()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('video');
   // $this->db->where('category',$category);
    return $this->db->get();
}


}
```

I am tring to display results from database in this way

```
<div>
first 10 results
</div>
<div>
 second 10 results
</div
<div>
rest from query
</div>
```

Can some one help me with logic

```
foreach($results as r)
{
   echo '<div>'.$r->video.'</div>';
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The question, as I read it is how to split an arbitrary number of entries into three dividers, two with 10 entries and then one with the rest.

Comment: Typo in the foreach, should be: `foreach($results as $r)` -- not clear if that is your question. Turn on error reporting.

Comment: add a counter `$x=1;`, increase it in the `foreach($results as $r)` -> `$x++;`, at 11, and 21, close out your div and start a new one - `</div><div>`. then close the last div outside the loop.

Comment: ^^ something **like** this: http://pastebin.com/QBZCEsc2

Comment: i wanna 10 video per div its simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$divisions = array(10,20);
for($i=0;$i<count($results);$i++){
    if($i===0){
        echo "<div>";
    }else if(in_array($i,$divisions){
        echo "</div><div>";
    }else if($i===count($results)-1){
        echo "</div>";
    }
    echo "<div>".$results[$i]->video."</div>";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you go. Tested and working.

```
<?php

//let's make a fake results array, just to show it works.
$results = array();


$c = 0;
while ($c < 100) {
        array_push($results, array('video' => 'a'));
        $c++;
}


//now for the actual answer.
$count = 0;
foreach ($results as $r) {
        if ($count === 0) {
                echo '<div>';
        }

        echo $r['video'] . ' ';

        if ($count === 9 || $count === 19) {
                echo '</div><div>';
        }

        $count++;
}

echo '</div>';

?>
```

Comment: FYI: What is if this link breaks? Does your post sill answers the question without all links?

Comment: Initially, the code would not be posted. It just wouldn't work. Then, just now, I managed to get it in properly.